# Can't figure out the meaning of this recursive code

Tags: c, recursion

I dont understand the meaning of this recursive code. Does it check whether any two values in contiguous two nodes are the same?

```
bool has_repeats(element_t *e) 
{
    if (e == NULL) 
       return false;
    if (contains_value(e->next, e->val)) 
       return true;
    return has_repeats(e->next);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Yes you know what you are talking about by answering your own question!  Checks the current node with the next node.  If they are the same it returns `true` else it recursively calls back to itself `return has_repeats(e->next);`.

I guess it would help us to see what `contains_value(x, y)` actually does.  As @Ben commented, more then likely `contains_value(x,y)` probably checks all values in the list.

Comment: I suspect `contains_value()` does not only check the next value but all values in the list. In this case, the function checks for duplicate, not only contigus duplicates (which makes sens considering its name)